Sending curl request from js
I was trying to send a request from the fetch() function to my Delhivery API from js application whose format looks like this:-

curl --request POST 
--url "https://track.delhivery.com/api/cmu/create.json" 
--header "Content-Type:application/json"
--header "Accept:application/json"
--header "Authorization: Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
--data 'format=json&data={
"shipments": [],
"pickup_location": {
"name": "Hello",
"add": "ABC123",
"city": "Delhi",
"pin_code": 813210,
"country": "India",
"phone": "1234567890"
}
}

I convert it into JSON but it seems it is always unable to detect format parameters.
I tried to send the body like this :

{
format : 'json',
data : {......other parameters
}
}

but it says missing format key in the POST data.
